# Why does my collection disappear when rendering with Eevee but is shown correctly when using Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am a beginner in Blender 2.8 and have used it only a few times so far. This time I tried to make a very reduced, basic animation. Everything worked fine during the work process, however as I tried to render my scene the following problem occured:
A whole collection (Arrow, Type, etc.) is not visible in the rendered version using Eevee. However, everything looks just fine when using Cycles. I did some research on the most common causes, but still was not able to figure out the problem. No object seems disabled from the render view and nothing seems to be hidden. Therefore I would appreciate some help!

Via the following Dropbox-Link you can access the blender file:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uqfxn7bhzzw4sx6/AACSmZ8ntv89tZnUb9wkMD86a?dl=0

[image]

Comment: Cannot see how to fix it, but Curve.001 is the cause. Delete that and the red marker circle/arrow shows.

Comment: Thank you!! Is there any possibilty to solve this/delete Curve.001 without having to redo the path-animation?

Comment: I really have no idea, normally I can go through all the settings and at some point find an option that was set wrong. What is extra weird is the fact that Cycles does render it. Hopefully someone else will be able to offer you a solution.